# Linux Script - supress single quote in date time

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am learning linux scripting, i rehearsed existing topics, please help.
Help required to avoid single quote in date time format am constructing a date time sring for last 2 mins like -' -e 2015-02-09 11:56.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 11:55.*INFO'

when i use the string in variable like `$X`
it converts like-: -e 2015-02-09 '11:56.*INFO' -e 2015-02-09 '11:55.*INFO'
with single quotes before time value

I need some help as how I can substitute `$x` as :
 -e '2015-02-09 11:56.*INFO' -e '2015-02-09 11:55.*INFO'

Below is my example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -x
TEST_HOME=/home/
TEST_HOME_FILE=/home/tempop.txt
LOG_FILE=/home/testlogMin.txt


echo "test before"
grepPattern=''
cnt=1
finalGrepPattern=''
timeInMin=2
while [[ $cnt -le $timeInMin ]]; do
        echo $cnt
    date_var=`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`
       #grepPattern=$grepPattern" -e "`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`".*INFO"
       #grepPattern=$grepPattern"  -e "`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`".*INFO"
       grepPattern="${grepPattern} -e ${date_var}"".*INFO"
       #grepPattern=$grepPattern" -e "`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`".*ERROR"
       #grepPattern=$grepPattern" -e "`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`".*WARNING"
       #grepPattern=$grepPattern" -e \""`date --date="$cnt minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`".*INFO"\" # I changed this line
      ((cnt++))
done

finalGrepPattern=$grepPattern
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
echo "$finalGrepPattern"
echo "*******"
echo $finalGrepPattern
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
if [ -s $LOG_FILE ]; then
        echo "File $LOG_FILE exists and its non-zero in size. Proceeding with greping last 10 mins file contents." 
    echo "$LOG_FILE"
    egrep $finalGrepPattern $LOG_FILE > $TEST_HOME/tempop.txt
    chmod 755 $TEST_HOME/tempop.txt
    echo "after egrep"
    if [ -s $TEST_HOME_FILE ]; then
        echo "$TEST_HOME_FILE is not empty. Sending  the file to XXXX server."
    fi
else
    echo "Did not find LOG_FILE GE ZERO"
fi
exit;
```

Below is output log from recent run:

```
[XXXXX@ccgtestserver ~]$ ./test
+ TEST_HOME=/home/XXXXX
+ TEST_HOME_FILE=/home/XXXXX/tempop.txt
+ LOG_FILE=/home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt
+ echo 'test before'
test before
+ grepPattern=''
+ cnt=1
+ finalGrepPattern=''
+ timeInMin=2
+ [[ 1 -le 2 ]]
+ echo 1
1
+ date '--date=1 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ date_var='2015-02-09 19:52'
+ grepPattern=' -e 2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO'
+ ((cnt++))
+ [[ 2 -le 2 ]]
+ echo 2
2
+ date '--date=2 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ date_var='2015-02-09 19:51'
+ grepPattern=' -e 2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO'
+ ((cnt++))
+ [[ 3 -le 2 ]]
+ finalGrepPattern=' -e 2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO'
+ echo '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
+ echo ' -e 2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO'
 -e 2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO
+ echo '*******'
*******
+ echo -e 2015-02-09 '19:52.*INFO' -e 2015-02-09 '19:51.*INFO'
2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO
+ echo '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
+ [ -s /home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt ]
+ echo 'File /home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt exists and its non-zero in size. Proceeding with greping last 10 mins file contents.'
File /home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt exists and its non-zero in size. Proceeding with greping last 10 mins file contents.
+ echo /home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt
/home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt
+ egrep -e 2015-02-09 '19:52.*INFO' -e 2015-02-09 '19:51.*INFO' /home/XXXXX/testlogMin.txt
+ 1> /home/XXXXX/tempop.txt
egrep: 19:52.*INFO: No such file or directory
egrep: 19:51.*INFO: No such file or directory
+ chmod 755 /home/XXXXX/tempop.txt
+ echo 'after egrep'
after egrep
+ [ -s /home/XXXXX/tempop.txt ]
+ exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a crude solution, best done before you concatenate the date string, using tr and sed:

```
x="2015-02-09 '11:56.*INFO'"

x=`echo "$x" | tr -d "'" | sed "s/\([0-9].*INFO\)/'\1'/g"`
```

Use if you have both date strings together and the '-e', it makes parsing difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You have no problem with single quotes. Quotes are added in debug output only and its because to avoid `*`(asterisks) expansion. Remove a debug flag `-x` in shebang. You can't modify a debug output:

```
+ echo -e 2015-02-09 '19:52.*INFO' -e 2015-02-09 '19:51.*INFO'
2015-02-09 19:52.*INFO -e 2015-02-09 19:51.*INFO
```

a line that starts with `+` its a debug output ;)

---

```
[/]$ ksh -c "echo *"
archive bin boot cdrom dev etc hdd home initrd.img initrd.img.old lib lib64 lost+found media mnt opt proc root run sbin source srv sys tmp usr var vertica vmlinuz vmlinuz.old

[/]$ ksh -c "echo '*'"
*
```